# Why does a explicit constructor expecting std::shared_ptr accept a nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, explicit

The following code compiles fine with gcc 4.8.1

```
#include <memory>

class Foo {
public:
     explicit Foo(const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& foo) {

     }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo(nullptr);
}
```

Why is this possible? Shouldn't the explicit prevent the compiler from calling std::shared_ptr(nullptr) implicitly?

Comment: As a note, a universal or otherwise `template` constructor can use SFINAE to do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't the explicit prevent the compiler from calling std::shared_ptr(nullptr) implicitly?

No, the explicit constructor would stop this from happening:

```
Foo foo = some_shared_ptr;
```

It has no effect on the constructors of `shared_ptr`, so implicit conversion from `nullptr` to `shared_ptr` is still allowed.